# c3.js : How to hide dots for specific data-set?

Tags: javascript, charts, c3.js

Suppose I have two dataset, data1 and data2 but I want to hide points/ circles on data2. How can I do it?

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
      columns: [
          ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
          ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ]
  }

})
```

Comment: A similar question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116623/c3-js-show-hide-points-independently-for-a-data-series), it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try This using CSS: Source [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vwQSxnSp6lR4us2IaoIu?p=preview). `c3-circles-data2` and `c3-circles-data1` are the classes generated by c3 for the given labels key like data1,data2.

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
      columns: [
          ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
          ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ]
  }
})
```

```css
#chart .c3-circles-data2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/c3@0.4.14/c3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/c3@0.4.14/c3.js"></script>
<div class='chart'>
<div id='chart'></div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** in case in you want to remove dots from both the series you can add

`point: {
        show: false
    }`

after data.

Comment: Thanks.. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

Not a js solution but for all the points c3 adds a class on the wrapper group element as `c3-circles-data1` `c3-circles-data2` for respective labels, which you can use for you data with label data2 which you can extend in css display none as :

```
#chart  .c3-circles-data2{
  display:none
}
```

Sample [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pkLfau39/12/)

Comment: Thanks. Solved my issue.